# Pandas - dataframe edit string from a single column with multiple (if) conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a follow dataframe, I would like to edit 'contact' column according to multiple conditions.

[Input DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IccHD.png)

```
start_date  contact            price  shop
2020-07-14  tel:858123456789  100.0  s1
2020-07-15  tel:+858123456789 100.0  s1
2020-07-16  tel:8123456789    50.0   s2
2020-07-17  tel:+8123456789   150.0  s3
```

dtype: 'contact' object

There are four conditions I need to check, and remove the beginning of the string accordingly

1. tel:858123456789 (at the beginning of value) => convert to => 8123456789
2. tel:+858123456789 => convert to => 8123456789
3. tel:8123456789 => convert to => 8123456789
4. tel:+8123456789 => convert to => 8123456789

I have tried with "for index in df_total.index:", iterating through row by row. It works but takes really long time, when I have 10 million rows to check.

Could you please suggest a solution with better performance?

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfTZB.png)

```
start_date  contact            price  shop
2020-07-14  8123456789         100.0  s1
2020-07-15  8123456789         100.0  s1
2020-07-16  8123456789         50.0   s2
2020-07-17  8123456789         150.0  s3
```

Comment: so, you need to remove "tel:" or "tel:+" from the beginning and "58" after the 1st number?

Answer (score 0):

```
df["contact"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["contact"].replace("tel", "").replace(":", "").replace("+", ""), axis=1)
```

This is just one way that is clear. You can try with regex as well.

Comment: This is really clean, I didn't know functions can be use like that. Thank you Prms. I already voted your answer. But somehow my votes are not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, i re created your data so the first part of the code is not so usefull to you but from the part I created the function is where you need to watch

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
start_date,contact,price,shop
2020-07-14,tel:858123456789,100.0,s1
2020-07-15,tel:+858123456789,100.0,s1
'''), sep=",")

print(df)

def check_str(col_vals):
    return [re.sub('\D', '', val) for val in col_vals]

cont = df['contact'].values
print(cont)
cont_trans = check_str(cont)
df["contact"] = cont_trans
print(df)
```

the output of this is

```
   start_date       contact  price shop
0  2020-07-14  858123456789  100.0   s1
1  2020-07-15  858123456789  100.0   s1
```

Comment: Thank you , Kim Rop. I didn't know objects can be use in functions like that. I learnt something new today thanks to you.